# Materialized date picker style postback issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, materialize, pickadate

I am using a materialized pickadate inside an UpdatePanel (ASP.Net) and I have detected an issue on postback.

Before postback:
[image: Before postback:]

After postback:
[image: After postback:]

I have implemented this script at the UpdatePanel start as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            prm.add_endRequest(function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('input.txt-00').characterCounter();
                    $(function () {
                        Materialize.updateTextFields();
                    });
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('select').material_select();
                });

                var today = new Date();  //Get today's date
                var minDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() - 99, 0, 0);
                var maxDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() - 2, 0, 0);
                $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
                    selectYears: 99, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
                    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    onClose: function () {
                        $(document.activeElement).blur();
                    },
                    hiddenName: true,
                    min: minDate,
                    max: maxDate
                });
...
```

I 've been googling for hours, no such issue found... Has anyone encountered this before? Thanks for any help...

Comment: You haven't really detailed what the problem is, is it that the green area dissapears?

Comment: The green area dissapears and the dropdown lists, bottom buttons and calendar style is messed up, my guess is that after postback it ignores the materialize style and just keeps the original pickadate style but I have no idea why is this happening and how to fix it...

Comment: I also noticed that after postback the date picker calendar is disabled so I can't change my option...